# Returning the fetched data from a ajax call to another function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have this javascript function, it sends an ajax requests to fetch a value from a php variable.

The function looks like so:

```
function get_cart_limit() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/w2w/ajax/',
    data: {
        _action: 'get_cart_limit'
    },
    type: 'post',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(output) {
        var cartlimit = output;
                    alert(cartlimit); // this gives me the correct value.
        return cartlimit;
    },
    error: function(output){

    }
});
```

}

When I call this function from another function like this:

```
var cartlimit = get_cart_limit();
```

my variable "cartlimit" is undefined.

So the ajax call is working, but why can't I return the value to another function?
To early for me, my brain isn't working properly! :)

Cheers!

Comment: since ajax call is asynchronous, it is normal that your variable is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the scope of the **cartlimit** variable and disable Asynchronous request, **get_cart_limit()** should return the correct value

```
function get_cart_limit() {
var cartlimit;
$.ajax({
    url: '/w2w/ajax/',
    data: {
        _action: 'get_cart_limit'
    },
    type: 'post',
    timeout: 10000,
    async: false,
    success: function(output) {
        cartlimit = output;

    },
    error: function(output){
    }
});
return cartlimit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but you will lock the browser until the request is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `cart_limit` is only set once the AJAX request successfully terminates.

Why?

1. The AJAX call is asynchronous, i.e. `get_cart_limit()` ends before the actual answer comes back from the server
2. The anonymous function that you specified as `success: function(output) { /*...*/ }` is called when the answer comes back from the server.

If you call another function that tries to access `cart_limit` before the success function has been executed, you will get an undefined value.

Even if you execute a return statement in the `success` function, it is a different function from get_cart_limit() and it gets executed at a different time, so you will not obtain the desired effect of assigning the return value to whatever variable.

One to solve this problem is to have the function that needs `cart_limit` be called by the anonymous success function.

```
function get_cart_limit() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/w2w/ajax/',
        data: {
            _action: 'get_cart_limit'
        },
        type: 'post',
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(output) {
            var cartlimit = output;
            alert(cartlimit); // this gives me the correct value.                
            function_that_needs_cart_limit();
        },
        error: function(output){
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare this **cartlimit** with a global scope. Decalre this before the function starts

```
var cartlimit;
function get_cart_limit() {
$.ajax({
...................
```

Here your cartlimit will be declared only after the ajax function get success .

But execution of another scripts may take before this success. So it will get undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your can pass your output data to the specified function like this

```
var cartlimit = get_cart_limit(output);
```